# angular6+electron, how to get upload file path, in one computer?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, electron

we project using angular6 and electron. I want to add a button to xxx.html, and click the button will choose one upload file, how can I get the file path?

thanks...

Comment: Did you try `<input type="file">`?

Comment: The browser will not allow this because of security concerns, maybe electron can be obtained, but...how do I get it ?

Comment: In electron you're in nodejs environment. So you can use the `fs` module

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I got it, html:

```
<input #selectFile type="file" (change)="getPath()"/>
```

ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild("selectFile") selectFile;

let path = this.selectFile.nativeElement.files[0].path;
```

now, the PATH is my wanted.

In browser,PATH is fakepath. In electron, PATH is realpath.